# Record deletion on Fluentd

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I need to write "Filter" or "record" in Fluentd where if the key `log` contains `INFO` then I need to delete the complete record, Any suggestion on how to write this?

```json
{
    "_index": "logstash-2021.06.19",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "nkeBI3oBrowj3sxE9hMv",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
        "log": "2021-06-19T08:57:31.118Z [INFO] 10.2.1.232:59778 - 44627 \"A IN xxxx. udp 66 false 512\" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 310 0.000114881s\n",
        "stream": "stdout",
        "docker": {
            "container_id": "4078ac6afdd2ec3bbacf148f442ad9a9eac8f92bb60b839114850e7c56157f8e"
        },
        "kubernetes": {
            "container_name": "coredns",
            "namespace_name": "kube-system",
            "pod_name": "coredns-6d699dcf7b-m6qmp",
            "container_image": "k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.5.0",
            "container_image_id": "docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/coredns@sha256:e83beb5e43f8513fa735e77ffc5859640baea30a882a11cc75c4c3244a737d3c",
            "pod_id": "69297648-e904-11e9-aad3-2a1c3f9db5a1",
            "labels": {
                "k8s-app": "coredns",
                "pod-template-hash": "6d699dcf7b",
                "tier": "control-plane"
            },
            "host": "da-cicd-enc1-bl6",
            "master_url": "https://10.3.0.1:443/api",
            "namespace_id": "5d2ccb8c-e904-11e9-aad3-2a1c3f9db5a1"
        },
        "@timestamp": "2021-06-19T08:57:31.119+00:00",
        "tag": "other_service.kubernetes.var.log.containers.coredns-6d699dcf7b-m6qmp_kube-system_coredns-4078ac6afdd2ec3bbacf148f442ad9a9eac8f92bb60b839114850e7c56157f8e.log"
    },
    "fields": {
        "@timestamp": [
            "2021-06-19T08:57:31.119Z"
        ]
    },
    "highlight": {
        "kubernetes.namespace_name": [
            "@kibana-highlighted-field@kube@/kibana-highlighted-field@-@kibana-highlighted-field@system@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
        ]
    },
    "sort": [
        1624093051119
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yes tried filtering with key level, but it look like it need a filter in key log
Need something that can read [INFO] from "log" string and then remove the complete event

<filter kubernetes.namespace_name:kube-system >
  @type grep
  <regexp>
    key level
    pattern fluent.(warn|error|fatal)
  </regexp>
</filter>

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68045398/edit) and add your configuration to the question along with any other related information.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used a [rewrite_tag_filter](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/rewrite_tag_filter) with 2 rules:

1. Check if the key ***log*** is **INFO**. If true re-emit this event with tag **toexclude**
2. Otherwise re-emit with tag **kube**. It's very important to use a different tag from the original to avoid infinite loop! So, don't use **kubeall** :D

```
<match kubeall>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key log
    pattern /^INFO$/
    tag toexclude
  </rule>
  <rule>
    key log
    pattern /.+/
    tag kube
  </rule>
</match>
```

Then, use a catch like this to delete the **toexclude** event

```
<match toexclude>
  @type null
</match>
```

Comment: Thanks for the above suggestion

Can we include any specific Namespace in the above suggestion?

Comment: Yes, of course. "kubeall", "kube" and "toexclude" are fancy names. Replace with what you want :)
You're Welcome